# How can I connect with strophejs using an email address as a user name.

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I am able to connect successfully to Open fire using strophe, unfortunately, when a users username is in the format of an email, the connection incorrectly uses everything that is after the first @ symbol as the domain. Then the connection does not work. 
Is this a bug or is this something that can be done differently (e.g by using some format to specify the domain some other way).

Thanks

Comment: I can see in the strophe code a function to unescape a node according to the spec http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0106.html . but it doesn't seem to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call Strophe.escapeNode(string to escape) before sending the username/jid to the server.

```
var jid = Strophe.escapeNode(foo@domain.com) + '@jabberserver.com';
```

Comment: Makes sense just that nowhere in the code the unescape function seem to be called. Am I using the wrong code? There is a core js file and also a strophejs, I am using the later.

Comment: It's there as a function if you need it along with a few others.

Comment: But if I escape it, and never gets unescaped in strophe, It will never connect. I ended up changing the username scheme but only because I had to get it working. I would like for it to accept the email.

Comment: Filed it as a bug, I don't think it works as expected, but it should work as Mark says. Ended up using a username that is not an email, which in my app I can control.